# Android Dialog with Spinner at bottom => dropdown not fully working

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, dialog, spinner

I have a simple dialog with an `EditText` and a `Spinner`... The Spinner only has two items and is at the bottom of the dialog...

When using dropdown-mode, only ONE item is shown in the dropdown list, if I'm using dialog-mode, all the items are shown...

Does anyone know a solution for that?

Here is my simple layout - it is not working correctly if I remove `android:spinnerMode="dialog"`...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etInput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Dialog code, nothing special in there...

```
public PromptAndSpinnerDialog(Context context, int title, int message, String text, int selectedIndex, Integer[] items, int okButtonID)
{
    super(context);
    theContext = context;
    setTitle(title);
    if (message > 0)
        setMessage(message);

    init(text, selectedIndex, items, okButtonID);
}

public PromptAndSpinnerDialog(Context context, int title, String message, String text, int selectedIndex, Integer[] items, int okButtonID)
{
    super(context);
    theContext = context;
    setTitle(title);
    setMessage(message);

    init(text, selectedIndex, items, okButtonID);
}

private void init(String text, int selectedIndex, Integer[] items, int okButtonID)
{
    View v = LayoutInflater.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dialog_prompt_and_spinner);
    setView(v);

    setPositiveButton(okButtonID, this);
    setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, this);

    getReferences(v);

    etInput.setText(text);
    etInput.selectAll();

    String[] strings = new String[items.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        strings[i] = theContext.getString(items[i]);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(theContext, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, strings);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spItems.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (selectedIndex != -1)
        spItems.setSelection(selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: put your activty code..

Comment: I added the code to my main post...

Comment: what is exactly do you want to do ? do you want to keep the `dialog` mode  and try to display the two items in your spinner ?

Comment: I want the `dropdown` mode, it's much more beautiful in my opinion... `dialog` mode is working anyways...